# What are common software packages used to draw fancy images in physics papers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, packages

In physics papers, we often see images aimed to explain a particular theoretical/experimental configuration considered. These images vary among 3D shapes to explain the mathematics (like stereographic representation) to actual experimental setups. They are often colourful drawing made fancier by shadows and effects.

Something simple and "plain" is feasible using the Tikz package of LaTex, but when it comes to more convoluted and fancy images I do not know what to use.

For example, the first images of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06213.pdf) or [this one](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.130504) show the conceptual process analysed in the paper. What software do you use to draw something similar?

Since different purposes will likely have different better software choices, every suggestion with relative preferred use is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Don't you think your question is a bit broad and also opinion-based? Not really suitable for the network.

Comment: I linked a paper as an example of images I am wondering about. I try to add some few details but I suppose it is meant to be opinion based since different people will use different software.

Comment: with good knowing of `tikz` and `pgfplots` packages and a lot of effort you can draw all mages in linked article.

Comment: I use IPE. It is good and allows Latex to be added on the diagrams. I use it for all my drawings now. 2D only. It does not work too well for 3D diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of the first paper is available from https://arxiv.org/format/1512.06213

Looking at the pdf meta data of figure 1, it was created with powerpoint

[image]

(I can't say anything about the second paper, it is hidden behind a paywall :( )

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is a step further I did not consider. I downloaded the source code but just noted the pdf. So I imagine Powerpoint can be a fast alternative to draw "setup" images.

Comment: @mekise You would need to ask the authors of the paper if using ppt is fast for producing such images